# Add and remove plugins to the plugin folder in a RCP application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am a newcomer to Eclipse plugin development. When I came across certain plugin concepts, some questions arose in my mind.

For a plugin based product, if we would like to add a new feature, say to perform certain validation, we just need to drop a particular plugin in which the validation logic is written. Similarly, if we would like to remove certain features from our product, we just require to remove the particular plugin providing the feature.

I tried to do the same operation in one of the RCP product build by me. I tried to remove a plugin from the plugin folder to disable a particular feature in my application. But it was getting the error message as below,

```
!MESSAGE Bundle com.my.app.application_1.0.0.201208101553 [6] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.my.app.application 2 0 2012-08-17 12:37:13.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.my.app.views.console_0.0.0.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-08-17 12:37:13.256
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "com.my.app.application.application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Could you please tell me why this error comes and how to overcome such errors?

Answer (score 2):

Each RCP product has a main plugin which defines an application (read more [Eclipse RCP Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse3RCP/article.html#components_rcp) by Lars Vogel). You removed a plugin which exports `com.my.app.views.console` package, but the package is required (imported) by the main plugin (`com.my.app.application`). Becuase of that, the main plugin couldn't be resolved and the application defined in that plugin couldn't be found - this is what you see in the exception message.

Comment: Hi Qinto,  thanks for your valuable reply. So how can i achieve the situation which i asked in my question? I would like to drop or remove some plugins from the plugin folder of my RCP product to achieve certain core functionality. But, just like you have specified, if a plugin imported by main plugin is not present in the plugin folder, it will throw an exception just like what i have shown in the above question. So , please suggest a method by which i can achieve the situation mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to remove the com.my.app.views.console plugin without breaking your application, you are going to have to find a way to remove the hard dependency that your com.my.app.application plugin has on your com.my.app.views.console plugin.

Comment: Hi twindham, Could you please guide me how can i remove the hard dependency

Comment: Sure.  Let's work through this exercise.  I'll assume you have both plugins open as projects in your development environment.  What I'm about to tell you to do will help you identify code that needs to change.  Step 1. Close the plugin project for the com.my.app.views.console plugin.  Step 2. Notice the compile errors that show up in the plugin project com.my.app.application plugin when you try to compile.  Step 3. Fix those compile errors by moving code from the com.my.app.views.console plugin into the com.my.app.application plugin.  Disclaimer: this may or may not work at all.